# Angular pagination with search query and move to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have a list of users and I am trying to paginate the table. The table uses an ng-repeat with multiple filters applied.

The table is shown below:

```
<input class='form-control' id='admin-search' ng-model='query' ng-change='setPage(0)'>

<table class='table table-striped'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='user in users | filter:query | pagination:currentPage * numPages() | limitTo: pageSize | orderBy:Sort.getOrderProp()'>
      <td>{{user.last}}</td>
      <td>{{user.first}}</td>
      <td>{{user.username}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ul class='pagination'>
  <li><a ng-click='previousPage()'>&laquo;</a></li>
  <li ng-repeat='n in range()'><a ng-click='setPage(n)'>{{n + 1}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click='nextPage()'>&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

The filters modify the results based on the search input at the top. I need my pagination to change with the query change. I use 'ng-change="setPage(0)"' which kind of works but doesn't remove the amount of pages shown in the pagination.

The pagination filter is used to filter the users based on the page size and current page.

```
app.filter 'pagination', ->
  (input, start) ->
    input = input || []
    start = +start;
    input.slice start
```

Right now, all my pagination code is in my user controller. Since it will be used in other controllers, I want to move most of it to a service, but doing so breaks it and does not update properly.

```
# Set up pagination
  $scope.currentPage = 0
  $scope.pageSize = 5

  $scope.numPages = ->
    Math.ceil($scope.users.length / $scope.pageSize) - 1

  $scope.nextPage = ->
    if $scope.currentPage < $scope.numPages()
      $scope.currentPage++

  $scope.previousPage = ->
    if $scope.currentPage > 0
      $scope.currentPage--

  $scope.setPage = (page) ->
    $scope.currentPage = page

  $scope.range = ->
    rangeSize = if 5 > $scope.numPages() then ($scope.numPages() + 1) else 5;
    ret = [];

    start = $scope.currentPage;

    if start > ($scope.numPages() - rangeSize)
      start = $scope.numPages() - rangeSize + 1;

    i = start
    while i < (start + rangeSize)
      ret.push i
      i++

    return ret;
```

I tried moving the above code to a service called pagination and injected it into my user controller but it doesn't update at all when the users changes if it is filtered.

So basically, my two questions are:

1. How can I reset pagination if I perform a search on the data
   (re-number the pagination element)
2. Move as much pagination code into
   a service as possible.

Comment: Any particular reason you are implementing pagination yourself? Have you considered using AngularUI-Bootstrap pagination directive? (Go to http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ - find for "Pagination")

Comment: I was looking into this, unless I am mistaking, it is just a wrapper for the pagination element. I will still need to create a filter for the content in my table and run into many of the same issues I already have.